# How to move a Canvas image using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Guys I am working on a code which needs to move an image in python using Tkinter(canvas)
This is creating problems for me. The image is being displayed but it is not moving.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Click me!")
def next_image(event):
    global toggle_flag
    global x, y, photo1
    # display photo2, move to right, y stays same
    canvas1.create_image(x+10, y, image=photo1)
    canvas1.create_image(x+20, y, image=photo1)           
    canvas1.create_image(x+30, y, image=photo1)
    canvas1.create_image(x+40, y, image=photo1)
    canvas1.create_image(x+50, y, image=photo1)
    canvas1.create_image(x+60, y, image=photo1)
    canvas1.create_image(x+70, y, image=photo1)
    canvas1.create_image(x+100, y, image=photo1)

image1 = "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pygame\examples\data\ADN_animation.gif"   #use some random gif
photo1 = PhotoImage(file=image1)
# make canvas the size of image1/photo1
width1 = photo1.width()
height1 = photo1.height()
canvas1 = Canvas(width=width1, height=height1)
canvas1.pack()
# display photo1, x, y is center (anchor=CENTER is default)
x = (width1)/2.0
y = (height1)/2.0
canvas1.create_image(x, y, image=photo1)
canvas1.bind('<Button-1>', next_image)  # bind left mouse click
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is creating 8 different images -- is that what you intend? Or did you intend to create a single image and moves 7 times?

Answer (score 7):

Canvas provides [`move`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.html#Tkinter.Canvas.move-method) method. Arguments are item you want to move, relative x offset from the previous position, y offset.

You need to save the return value of the `create_image` to pass it to the `move` method.

Also make sure the canvas is expandable (`pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)` in the following code)

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def next_image(event):
    canvas1.move(item, 10, 0) # <--- Use Canvas.move method.

image1 = r"C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pygame\examples\data\ADN_animation.gif"
photo1 = PhotoImage(file=image1)
width1 = photo1.width()
height1 = photo1.height()
canvas1 = Canvas(width=width1, height=height1)
canvas1.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH) # <--- Make your canvas expandable.
x = (width1)/2.0
y = (height1)/2.0
item = canvas1.create_image(x, y, image=photo1) # <--- Save the return value of the create_* method.
canvas1.bind('<Button-1>', next_image)
root.mainloop()
```

---

**UPDATE according to the comment**

Using `after`, you can schedule the function to be called after given time.

```
def next_image(event=None):
    canvas1.move(item, 10, 0)
    canvas1.after(100, next_image) # Call this function after 100 ms.
```

Comment: @fasetru : sir this was when I need to click the mouse button. But what if I want the image to move from one side of screen to other and then emerge from left side of screen and then move to right.

Comment: @user3475345, Specify negative value for the initial position: `item = canvas1.create_image(-x, y, image=photo1)`

Comment: sir but with this the image will only move when I press the left mouse button . I want the image to move without any event.

Comment: @user3475345, I updated the answer. If you have another question, please post a separated question.