# How do I update canvas and images in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

This is a section of code which I use to display a chess board in a window:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 

def render():
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry("1920x1080")
    window.title("Chess 2")

    frame = tk.Frame(window)
    frame.pack()

    canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, width=800, height=800)
    canvas.pack()

    boardImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = r"successful projects\imgs\board.png")
    canvas.create_image(400,400,image=boardImg)

    whitePawnImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = r"successful projects\imgs\whitePawn.png")
    # ...

    for y in range(len(board)):
        for x in range(len(board[y])):
            match board[y][x]:
                case "p":
                    canvas.create_image(50+(x*100),50+(y*100),image=blackPawnImg) 
                # ...
                case _:
                    pass 
    window.mainloop()
```

In the code, "board" is a representation of a chess board like so (shortened):

```
[[' ', ' '],
[' ', 'p']]
```

When I call `render()`, everything works fine. Trouble is, when I change the list to eg.

```
[[' ', 'p'],
[' ', ' ']]
```

, then call `render()` again, the window stays the same. What I want is for the board to render everything again. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Each time you call render you are creating a whole new window.

Comment: Okay, is there a way to update the current window with moved images? canvas.move?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275445/move-an-image-in-python-using-tkinter) stack overflow post answer your question r.e. moving images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add things to a `Canvas` widget, using one of its `create_xxx()` methods, like [`create_image()`](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/create_image.html), an integer `id` number is returned which you could use to move the object later via its [`move()`](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/canvas-methods.html) method.
That's all you have need to do to update what's being displayed, no explicit "refresh" step is needed.

For example, if you initially placed a pawn image somewhere using:

```
pawn_id = canvas.create_image(50+(x*100), 50+(y*100), image=blackPawnImg)
```

You could move the pawn image 10 pixels to the right and 20 down via (note that the movement amounts are specified relative to its current position):

```
canvas.move(pawn_id, 10, 20)
```

You can also use the more generic `itemconfigure()` method to change other options associated with `Canvas` items (such as the color of a line created with `create_line()`).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to anything to update the canvas other than to draw, redraw, delete, or move objects on the canvas. Whenever you add something to a canvas, the canvas will add an event to the event queue telling tkinter that the widget needs to be refreshed. The next time control returns to `mainloop`, the canvas will automatically be refreshed.

Your code has a fundamental flaw that each call to `refresh` will create an entirely new window, entirely new canvas, etc. Instead, your `refresh` should work with an existing window and canvas, and all it needs to do is move items around. The window itself will automatically refresh once the function returns.